# Running SQOOP throws Server IPC version 7 cannot communicate with client version 3

Tags: pentaho, sqoop

I'm trying to a Pentaho Kettle Job with SQOOP plugin to export a table from ORACLE and import the same into HDFS.

I'm using cloudera CDH4 (4.2) demo VM and using the Hadoop jars and Sqoop jar that comes with the demo VM.

I see that the version of org.apache.hadoop.ipc.CURRENT_VERSION is set to 7. One thing, I'm unable to figure out here is, who is the client here and how do I check the version? Is Sqoop the client in this context?

Any suggesstion would be really helpful.

*Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: Server IPC version 7 cannot communicate with client version 3
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:740)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:220)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.$Proxy23.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:359)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.createRPCProxy(JobClient.java:429)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.init(JobClient.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.(JobClient.java:410)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.(Job.java:50)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runImport(ImportJobBase.java:188)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.importTable(SqlManager.java:413)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.OracleManager.importTable(OracleManager.java:380)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:380)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:453)*

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some version mismatch problem. Try this and see if it helps :

Replace the hadoop-*-core.jar present in your $PDI_HOME/libext/bigdata/ directory with the one which has come with CDH4.